# Xamarin - Assign textchange and unfocus event to a Textbox (Password)

Tags: xaml, xamarin

My XAML file looks like this

```
   <local:PlainEntry IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Pwd"
    x:Name="contrasenaEntry" HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"  Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0"/>
```

Is there a way to fire and Onchange and unfocus event on the text field Password I tried with Password.myElement.IsFocused it doesn't work. I tried

```
private void PasswordEditText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("text has changed!");
    // this is not working!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows you are binding to the property "Password", this looks like you are using MVVM, BUT then that method you have written looks like it is a code behind method.

If you are using code behind you will want to use something like this..

```
<local:PlainEntry IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Pwd"
x:Name="contrasenaEntry" HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
VerticalOptions="Center" TextChanged="PasswordEditText_TextChanged" 
Margin="0"/>
```

Then call the method you already have

```
private void PasswordEditText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("text has changed!");
    // this is not working!
}
```